# Change color text with click on Angular

Tags: html, css, typescript

I want to make a simple thing that the user input a color that he choose and make the color begin on some paragraph .

The input and the click button that the user send the `inputColor` to the typescript  :

```
<form>
    <input #inputColor  type="text"/>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeColorText(inputColor)"></button>
    </form>
```

The function `changeColorText()` on the typescript :

```
export class HelloWorld implements OnInit {
public inputColor:string;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public changeColorText(str:string) :void {
    this.inputColor = str;
  }

}
```

**The problem :**

The paragraph change the color if i choose one (Witout input from the user) :

```
<p style="color:blue">Hello World !</p>
```

But I want what the user put in the box to make the paragraph like the color that sent, I couldn't find the correct syntax here:

```
<p style="color:{{inputColor}}">Hello World !</p> // ERROR !!!!

<p style=`color:{{inputColor}}`>Hello World !</p> // No compilation error .. but not working:
```

Comment: initialize it `public inputColor:string=''`;

Comment: How is it even compiling if you have `(click)="changeColorText(inputColor)"` and `inputColor` is not a string but an `HTMLElement`?

Comment: Hey pc_coder , its not working , Balastrong you say the problem is with #inputColor?

Comment: I added one answer demo for you and explanation answer. You can check it @Pluto

Answer (score 1):

You should use a style binding as following, details can be found at https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax:

```
<p [style.color]="inputColor" >Hello World !</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
<form>
    <input #inputColor  type="text"/>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeColorText(inputColor.value)">ClickMe</button>
</form>

<p style="color: {{inputColor.value}}">Hello World !</p>
```

You have to take the value from inputColor as it's an HTMLElement on this side.

---

Another option, is to have different names from the element and your string, for example:

```
<form>
    <input #inputColor  type="text"/>
    <button type="button" (click)="changeColorText(inputColor.value)">ClickMe</button>
</form>

<p style="color: {{inputColorStr}}">Hello World !</p>
```

With

```
  public inputColorStr: string;

  public changeColorText(str: string): void {
    this.inputColorStr = str;
  }
```